# Checkbox autocomplete not select previous checked value in Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on "Autocomplete ajax search" using Php, I am fetching data from
database succesfully,Right now whenever i search something then result with checkbox is showing
,But whenever i search any text and check any "checkbox" and then search another text and check another checkbox then previous checkbox also should post,But with current code only current checkbox(showing in screen) value post
,How can i post all "checked checkbox value"(checbox with previous search and current search)? Here is my code

```
<input type="text" id="autouser" name="coin" class="form-control">
            <div id="resultDiv"></div>
        

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#autouser" ).autocomplete({
         source: function( request, response ) {
          // Fetch data
          $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>main/CoinReords',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              search: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                $("#resultDiv").html("");
                $.each(data, function(i, record) {
                    console.log(record.label);
                $("#resultDiv").append("<input type='checkbox' value='" + record.label + "' id='chk-" + i + "' name='CoinName[]' /> " + record.label);
  });
            }
          });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#autouser').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
          $('#resultDiv').selectedItems.push(ui.item.label); 
          return false;
        }
      });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code with GET method to get the string and all the data is being transferred. The code seems good. There must be something wrong with your code which is receiving the data. You can further comment below this answer if you want to add something to your query.

Comment: Let me explain, For example right now i search some text "abc" then list of options with checkbox showing and i select 4 checkboxes and then i search another text "Xyz" then again i checked 3 checkbox then total "7" checkbox value should post but right not only latest values (3) is posting , i want to post "previous" + "current"  data

Comment: var mew = $("#resultDiv input:checked");
            $('#resultDiv').html('');
            mew.each(function (item, value) { $('#resultDiv').append(value) });
            $("#resultDiv").append("<input type='checkbox' value='v' name='coinname[]' /> ");

Comment: Enter this code before you append new items coming from ajax